# Cycles - Alpha in output file appears to be 1bit

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image, transparency

I've a surface (mesh>plane subdivided) with an image used for transparency, in Cycles. Rendering gives a good clean edge on the transparency, however the output file alpha appears to be 1bit depth.

This is in Cycles, I have transparency switched on in the Film section of the rendering properties. I have RGBA on and 16 bit png output file, though I've tried tiff and others etc.

You can see in the screen grab on the right is the rendered frame in Blender, nice and smooth, on the left is the file displayed in Photoshop.

[image]

Comment: I am not a PS user but it looks like image interpolation is set to Nearest Neighbour. Check out this short video to see how to change to Linear of Bicubic. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLFRtOoF53I or do further search that explains the difference between Nearest Neighbour and Linear or Bicubic Interpolation.

Comment: Sorry this isn't a photoshop issue, it's how blender is saving the image or not rendering correctly in the first place. I only mentioned photoshop simply to show how I was viewing the output frame, but it's the same in after effects or even image preview on the Mac.